# Relacionar tabelas em uma só query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Eu preciso de uma query que retorne para cada mapa os players que tiveram batalhas nele, a quantidade de batalhas que cada player teve(no respectivo mapa), o tempo total jogado(por player no respectivo mapa), e a quantidade de transgressões(por player no respectivo mapa). As tabelas são: classification, battles e trangressor_list e estão estruturadas como o seguinte:

classification

Id | Player_Id | Battle_Id | Time_Played

---

battles

Id | Map_Id

---

trangressor_list

Id | Transgressor_Id | Battle_Id

---

A querie que eu tentei foi a seguinte:

```
SELECT Map_Id, Player_Id, COUNT(Player_Id) AS Quantidade, SUM(Time_Played) AS 'Time Played'
FROM classification, battles, trangressor_list
WHERE  classification.Battle_Id = battles.Id AND trangressor_list.Battle_Id = battles.Id
GROUP BY Player_Id, Map_Id
ORDER BY Map_Id ASC, Player_Id ASC
;
```

isso funciona parcialmente, mas não é exatamente o que eu preciso

Comment: A coluna Transgressor _Id contém a identificação do jogador? // Em uma mesma batalha o jogador pode ter mais de uma transgressão? // Você pode acrescentar amostra de dados para teste?

Comment: sim, Transgressor _Id contém a identificação do jogador e pode ter mais de uma transgressão por batalha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Usando subqueries**

```
SELECT subq.*
      ,QtdTransgressoes = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tra.Transgressor_Id)
                             FROM classification as cla
                             JOIN trangressor_list as tra 
                                  ON tra.Battle_Id = cla.Battle_Id
                            WHERE cla.Player_Id = subq.Player_Id)
  FROM (SELECT Map_Id
              ,Player_Id
              ,COUNT(Player_Id) AS Quantidade
              ,SUM(Time_Played) AS TimePlayed
         FROM classification
         JOIN battles ON classification.Battle_Id = battles.Id
        GROUP BY Player_Id, Map_Id) as subq
  ORDER BY Map_Id ASC, Player_Id ASC
```

**Usando CTE**

```
WITH Tab1 (Map_Id, Player_Id, Quantidade, TimePlayed)
AS
(
     SELECT Map_Id
           ,Player_Id
           ,COUNT(Player_Id) 
           ,SUM(Time_Played) 
      FROM classification
      JOIN battles ON classification.Battle_Id = battles.Id
     GROUP BY Player_Id, Map_Id
)
,
Tab2 (Player_Id, QtdTransgressoes)
AS
(
     SELECT cla.Player_Id
           ,COUNT(DISTINCT tra.Transgressor_Id)
       FROM classification as cla
       JOIN trangressor_list as tra ON tra.Battle_Id = cla.Battle_Id
      GROUP BY cla.Player_Id
 )
 SELECT Tab1.*
       ,Tab2.QtdTransgressoes
   FROM Tab1
   LEFT JOIN Tab2 ON Tab2.Player_Id = Tab1.Player_Id
  ORDER BY Map_Id ASC, Player_Id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Considerando-se que em uma batalha um jogador possa ter no máximo uma transgressão registrada, eis sugestão:

```
-- código #1
SELECT B.Map_Id, C.Player_Id, 
       count(B.Id) as [Qtd batalhas],
       sum(C.Time_Played) as [Tempo jogado],
       count(T.Id) as [Qtd transgressões]
  from battles as B
       inner join classification as C on C.Battle_Id = B.Id
       left join trangressor_list as T on T.Transgressor_Id = C.Player_Id
                                          and T.Battle_Id = B.Id
  group by B.Map_Id, C.Player_Id;
```

Se houver a possibilidade de mais de uma transgressão por batalha (para um mesmo jogador), altera-se a forma como são contabilizadas.